# Prove that $\int_0^1(\int_0^xf(x,y)dy)dx=\int_0^1(\int_0^yf(x,y)dx)dy= \frac12\int_Af(x,y)dxdy$

Tags: calculus, integration

If $\ f:A = [0,1]\times[0,1] \to \mathbb R$ continuous, such that $\ f(x,y) = f(y,x) \ \forall(x,y)\in A$

Prove:

$\int_0^1(\int_0^xf(x,y)dy)dx=\int_0^1(\int_0^yf(x,y)dx)dy= \frac12\int_Af(x,y)dxdy$

I have found similar questions, but none of them can help me understand how to do this.

I found this here: [Ejercicio 4](https://www.cubawiki.com.ar/index.php/Final_22/02/2019_(An%C3%A1lisis_II))

Comment: I realized that the integration region of the first two integrals are equal triangles, but I do not realize how to prove that they are equal to the last member.

Comment: I like to think about it geometrically. What is the region over which you are integrating in the first integral? What about the second one? What does your condition on $f$ mean? (Hint: $f$ is symmetric along a line).

Comment: Then, the first integral would be on a triangle of base 1, height x.
The second, a triangle but turned.
And the third integral would be an integral equals to the union of two triangles of that style?

Comment: The first integral is a right triangle with length and height one with the hypotenuse the line joining $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ and similarly the second one. And you are right about the last part.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$A=\{(x,y)\mid 0\leq y\leq x\leq 1 \}\cup\{(x,y) \mid 0\leq x\leq y\leq 1\}.$$